# Display a video from my external mysql database on a webpage with php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to display an mp4 file I have on an external mysql database(freesqldatabase.com) to my local website(localhost).

```
$host2="----.freesqldatabase.com";
$user2="-----";
$password2="-----";
$dbname2="-----";

//create connection
$con2 = mysqli_connect($host2, $user2, $password2, $dbname2);

//check connection
if (!$con2){
    die("connection failed: " .mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

```
<?php
    include("config.php");

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            video{
                float: left;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
        <?php
        $fetchVideos = mysqli_query($con2, "SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY id DESC");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetchVideos)){
            $location = $row['location'];
            echo "<div >";
            echo "<video src='' controls width='320px' height='200px' >";
            echo "</div>";
            print_r($row);
        }

        ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Normally you'd put a path to the video file in src=' ', but it's stored in an external database so I don't know what to put there.
I think you have to use a mysql connection url somewhere but I don't know how to do that exactly and couldn't find any tutorials about it.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavours from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Use this style: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and isn't the best option in new code.

Comment: `a mysql connection url` ... huh? mysql databases aren't web applications, you don't connect to them via a URL. Maybe you mean hostname? Are you getting a specific error or problem in your code? Maybe an unexpected result, or something? Obviously we don't know if you set the hostname, username and password of the database server correctly or not, but otherwise there's nothing particularly wrong-looking about what you've written. Please be more specific about what problem you're trying to solve here.

Comment: -ADyson I don't know what to put in " src=' ' ". Normally you'd put a path to the video file there, but it's stored in an external database so I don't know what to put there.

Comment: What exactly is stored in the database? Is it the name of the file, or the binary data of the video, or what? Remember we can't see your data, unless you give us some samples of rows from the `videos` table.

Comment: The video name and binary data is stored in the database.

Comment: Storing large binary objects in the database is almost always a really bad plan. Not only does this massively complicate any backup and restore procedure, it also makes streaming video near impossible as you will likely need to load the entire file into memory as it's transmitted. Files on disk have way more options, including sending in parts, and using kernel-level streaming optimizations.

Comment: And as you're discovering now, it also complicates the business of serving them in a HTML document because you don't have a ready made URL. I would agree, store the files on disk somewhere, in cloud storage or whatever.